# what it means "Очковая диета"?

Tags: значения, словоупотребление

as an example in the name of the diet
for example [Очковая диета](http://evehealth.ru/ochkovaya-dieta-khudeem-po-novomu/)

Comment: Очки here stand for "points". Each meal has a number of points. A person tries to gather as less points per day as possible in order to lose weight.

Comment: @Artemix, I think this should be the answer, it is the correct description of the meaning.

Answer (score 3):

***Очковая диета*** simply means that instead of calories, you count points (*очки* or *баллы*). Counting points is presumed to be easier than counting calories, mainly because the diet is accompanied by a comprehensive list of things you can eat and their assigned points, no background in nutritional science necessary. If you want to lose weight, you need stay within the daily point limit.

The Atkins diet is one famous example of a points diet, Weight Watchers is another.